# Backchannels (listener responses) in Spanish

Tags: lingüística, conversación, vocabulario

In linguistics, the term *[backchannel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-channel#In_linguistics)* is used to describe the short words or sounds a listener makes during a conversation to acknowledge what the speaker is saying and make known that he is still paying attention. For example, in English this would include:

- Mm-hmm
- Yeah
- Wow!
- Definitely
- Really?
- Ahh
- Ok

What are the most common listener responses like this in Spanish? What situations is each used in (for example, agreement, acknowledgement, surprise)?

Comment: I think it's onomatopeya what you are looking for.

Comment: @Joze: An *onomatopoeia* is a word that imitates a sound it's describing (like "meow"). Backchanneling is a separate concept (check the Wikipedia page I linked above).

Comment: Oh! my bad! now I understand! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spanish people also make the noises we do in these situations, eg ahh, mm-hmm

Other words someone might use in the situation you mentions are

- Ok
- En serio?! (Really?!)
- Bueno (Ok)
- Dale (Ok then, as in like, ok then do that)
- Wow (wau, uau, however you want to spell it)

Comment: What about "¿Verdad?" for "Really?"... I've always used that, although I've seen "En serio" before.

Comment: yeah verdad is used too

Answer (score 2):

I can think of several that I use personally:

- ¿En serio? (Seriously?)
- Ajá (Indicating that I'm still paying attention)
- Wow (Same as in English)
- OK (Same as in English)
- ¡No jodás! ("Get out of here" would be the equivalent in English)

Comment: Wouldn't the last example be translated a lot more strongly than "Get out of here"?

Comment: @jrdioko: It depends on the context of the conversation. `¡No jodás!` in the context of you listening to someone else narrating some facts unrelated to you, is more like saying `get out of here!` (indicating surprise). On a different context in may very well indicate more like `don't fuck with me!`. And yes, the right word would be `fuck` instead of `mess`. The verb `joder` is something you shouldn't use lightly :)

Comment: ¡No jodás!* doesn't have written accent on letter "a". It should be "¡no jodas!" because the stressed sylable is "jo". And it also means something like "really?" when you come across an unexpected problem and you can't bealieve it. This use is very common.

Comment: @Javi Although your comment is right for Spain, in some Latin America regions "No jodás" is very usual.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some that would work well in Mexico:

- ¿Ah sí?
- No me diga/digas.
- ¿De veras?
- ¿En serio?
- Mmm (voice going up at the end)
- Pues sí / pues no (this affirms that the person's reaction was reasonable)
- ¿Y entonces? (this encourages the person to continue after a pause)
- Ah caray (oh jeesh, oh gosh)
- ¡Caramba! (Jesus H Christ!)