# «¿Ah, sí?» o «¿Así?»: ¿Son posibles las dos?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, conversación

Me pregunto si en una conversación la gente está diciendo «¿Ah, sí?» o «¿Así?» para mostrar que está escuchando. ¿O cambia dependiendo del contexto?

No estoy preguntando de una conversación técnica, en la que se mostraría cómo hacer algo.

Por ejemplo, un diálogo sencillo:

> —Vivía en Chile.
>   —**¿Ah, sí?**
>   —Así es.

o está diciendo:

> —Vivía en Chile.
>   —**¿Así?**
>   —Así es.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En este caso solamente es correcta la primera forma:

> —Vivía en Chile.
>   —**¿Ah, sí?**
>   —Así es.

Recordemos que [*ah*](https://dle.rae.es/?w=ah) es una interjección usada, según el DLE, *para denotar pena, admiración, sorpresa o sentimientos similares*. Además, también según el DLE, en América se usa para interrogar. Por tanto, aquí uno usa *ah, sí* como ['backchannel'](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/817/1674).

---

Para que la segunda fuera correcta, la pregunta debería centrarse en el *cómo*, para que el adverbio [*así*](https://dle.rae.es/?w=as%C3%AD) pudiera introducir una modalidad.

Por ejemplo, imagina que estás visitando una casa-museo de alguien famoso:

> —Vivía en esta casa.
>   —**¿Así?**
>   —Así, sí, con apenas una habitación y treinta y cinco hijos.

Answer (score 1):

Concuerdo con que el "Así" es de una forma omanera como ser una persona enseñando a hacer algo a otra persona y la segunda imitando las indicaciones de la primera le pregunta "¿Así? ¿Así está bien?".

-Tienes que lavarte las manos de esta manera
-¿Así?
-Sí, muy bien